# How to remember the cart items for a particular user in e-commerce using Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

I'm not able to understand how to store items in a cart for different users.

Comment: For every user's session, you'll have the info in DB if they have items added in cart.

Comment: what is your database